# HIVE - INSERT OVERWRITE vs DROP TABLE + CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO

Tags: hive, hiveql, create-table, hiveddl

I'm doing some automatic script of few queries in hive and we found that we need time to time clear the data from a table and insert the new one. And we are thinking what could be faster?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE SOME_TABLE
    SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE;
```

or is faster to do like this:

```
DROP TABLE SOME_TABLE;
CREATE TABLE SOME_TABLE (STUFFS);
INSERT INTO TABLE
    SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE;
```

The overhead of running the queries is not an issue. Due to we have the script o creation too. The question is, the `INSERT OVERWRITE` with billion of rows is faster than `DROP + CREATE + INSERT INTO`?

Comment: `Insert OVERWRITE` make sure that previous data is been removed from HDFS and only new data available in table/partition. `DROP + CREATE + INSERT INTO` might not guaranty the same.

Comment: @Ambrish why is that/can you provide a source? I would assume drop table removes the table and all old data entirely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For maximum speed I would suggest to 1) issue `hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash table_dir/*` first to remove old data fast without putting files into trash because INSERT OVERWRITE will put all files into Trash and for very big table this will take a lot of time. Then 2) do `INSERT OVERWRITE` command. This will be faster also because you do not need to drop/create table.

**UPDATE:**

As of Hive 2.3.0 (HIVE-15880), if the table has `TBLPROPERTIES ("auto.purge"="true")` the previous data of the table is not moved to Trash when `INSERT OVERWRITE` query is run against the table. This functionality is applicable only for managed tables. So, INSERT OVERWRITE with auto purge will work faster than `rm -skipTrash` + `INSERT OVERWRITE` or `DROP`+`CREATE`+`INSERT` because it will be a single Hive-only command.

Comment: is this applicable for partitions as well? If auto.purge is set to true, when insert overwrite to partition, that partitions old data will also not be moved to trash?

Comment: @uptoNoGood yes, it should delete old data in partitions being overwritten without moving to thrash

Answer (score 6):

One edge consideration is that if your schema changes, `INSERT OVERWRITE` will fail, while `DROP`+`CREATE`+`INSERT` will not. While this is unlikely to apply in most scenarios, if you're prototyping workflow/table schemas then it might be worth considering.