# Drop and overwrite external table in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hiveddl

I need to create an external table in hiveql with the output from a SELECT clause. Every time when the HiveQL is ran the table should be dropped and recreated . When we drop an external table only the table structure is getting dropped but not the data files from HDFS location. How to achieve this?

Comment: After recreating the table, how do you load data?

Comment: I was referring to create table <tablename> as select * from table2;

Comment: why do you want to drop and re-create the external table? is it to remove data and overwrite it with new data from table as part of select cluase?

Comment: Yes. It is to overwrite the data.

Comment: if you only want to overwrite data, why should you drop the table? Can you not simply copy and overwrite the data into that external location? or you could use `LOAD DATA INPATH...OVERWRITE INTO TABLE...`

Answer (score 2):

Create Table As Select ([CTAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS))) has restrictions. One of them is that target table cannot be External.

You have these options:

1. Create external table once, then INSERT OVERWRITE

   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename1 [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)  select_statement1 FROM from_statement;
2. Use managed table, then you can `DROP TABLE`, then `CREATE TABLE ... as SELECT`

See also answer about [skipTrash and auto.purge property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39623927/2700344).