# Increase the performance of the insert overwrite in hive managed table

Tags: performance, hive, insert, hiveql, overwrite

I'm new to Hive and I wanted to know the list of table properties to increase the performance of the insert overwrite in hive managed table.
Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Switch-off statistics auto-gathering:

   `set hive.stats.autogather=false;`
2. Remove partitions folders or table folder in advance if possible, or use PURGE option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39623927/2700344
3. If you are using S3 and table is ORC, disable block-padding:

   `ALTER TABLE your_table SET TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.block.padding"="false", "orc.block.padding.tolerance"="1.0");`
4. Use vectorization [ConfigurationProperties-Vectorization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Vectorization) and Tez:

   `set hive.execution.engine=tez;`
5. Optimize query.